# How to change selected view highlight in WinUI 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, winui-3

How to change the appearance (e.g height, width, color, position, etc.) of the selected view indicator (the blue line)?

1. TextBox example:
   [image: TextBox example]
2. ComboBox example:
   [image: ComboBox example]

---

Edit 1:
This is the only thing I found on the internet and it **DIDN'T** work.

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush 
        x:Key="ComboBoxItemBackgroundSelected" Color="#FF0000" />
    <SolidColorBrush 
        x:Key="ComboBoxItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="#FF0000" />
 </ComboBox.Resources>
```

Comment: You will have to define your own custom `ControlTemplate` for the `ComboBox`.

Comment: You need to custom ComboBox's  ItemContainerStyle,

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this is, You should create your own style for ComboBoxItem (not ComboBox) or pull out the default ComboBoxItem style from generic.xaml and add modifications as per your need.

I have implemented the solution for this in my application. The selection highlighter will be a rectangle control used within the control template of `DefaultComboBoxItemStyle` style.I have overridden the `DefaultComboBoxItemStyle` style as mentioned below,

1. I have overridden the `DefaultComboBoxItemStyle` style and modified the selection pill to use my own style.

The snippet of selection rectangle pill,

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Pill" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemPill}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Opacity="0">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform x:Name="PillTransform" ScaleY="1" />
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

2. In that pill style i have used my own color.

Snippet,

```
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemPill" TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemPillHeight}" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemPillWidth}" />
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource ComboBoxItemPillCornerRadius}, Converter={StaticResource TopLeftCornerRadiusDoubleValueConverter}}" />
        <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource ComboBoxItemPillCornerRadius}, Converter={StaticResource BottomRightCornerRadiusDoubleValueConverter}}" />
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5" />
    </Style>
```

Complete `DefaultComboBoxItemStyle` style with visual state groups,

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" x:Key="DefaultComboBoxItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemThemePadding}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemCornerRadius}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="5,2,5,2" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Pill" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBackgroundSelected}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBorderBrushSelected}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundSelected}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Pill" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBackgroundSelectedUnfocused}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBorderBrushSelectedUnfocused}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundSelectedUnfocused}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedDisabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Pill" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBackgroundSelectedDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBorderBrushSelectedDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundSelectedDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Pill" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBorderBrushSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Pill" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PillTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemScaleAnimationDuration}" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemPillMinScale}" KeySpline="0,0,0,1" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemBorderBrushSelectedPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemForegroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputModeStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="InputModeDefault" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="TouchInputMode">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemThemeTouchPadding}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            
                            <VisualState x:Name="GameControllerInputMode">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxItemThemeGameControllerPadding}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Rectangle x:Name="Pill" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemPill}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Opacity="0">
                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform x:Name="PillTransform" ScaleY="1" />
                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    </Rectangle>

                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Hope it helps!